# How to externalize Hibernate 3.6 configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, configuration, hibernate.cfg.xml

I have an app which uses Hibernate 3.6.3 as the ORM. I created the hibernate.cfg.xml configuration file and added it to the build path. This works fine in my development environment. Now I need to create a jar for the production server with a dynamic DB connection credentials. I spent couple of hours on searching how to do it but all of the examples use:

- Spring: which is not on the list of "blessed technologies",
- Separate maven profiles: for which I need to now the production
  credentials (this won't happen).

Can I separate hibernate DB configurations or I need to pass it as parameter and configure hibernate programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already proposed two solutions:

- build-time configuration (using Maven), but you don't have the credentials at build-time
- run-time configuration resolving, which can be done:

  1. Using Spring (which you can't use)
  2. Using your own programmatic mechanism:

     ```
     Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
     configuration.configure();

     configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", dbUrl);
     configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", dbUser);
     configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", dbPassword); 

     return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
     ```

Comment: I hope there is a way to extract config to the MyConf.properties somehow but "configuration.setProperty" will do.